# How to deploy Java/Spring application on my own system in Apache tomcat server.?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

Hello all master minds,

I have created a java spring application in eclipse with mysql db.

Now I can run this application using >Run on server in eclipse,but I want to know how to deploy this application on my own laptop(windows 7).

I have already configured server,by `localhost://8080` I can see Apache tomcat is configured.

Give me simple steps so that i can just run that software using browser via its link like

```
http://localhost:8080/PMS
```

PMS is my project name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Tomcat Web Application Deployment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html).

Comment: Should I learn maven or ant build tool?

Comment: If you can build a self-sufficient WAR file then you can deploy it without automation tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `tomcat-manager` in order to deploy your war using a web interface: [Tomcat 7 manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)

Another option is to copy your war file into tomcat `webapps` folder. Your container will auto deploy your war: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Deployment_With_Tomcat.

Comment: If i do this then there will be no need to learn ant or maven.?
and for war file eclipse is sufficient?

Comment: @ZaidKhan you need to 'export' your project in war bundle, executing war task of maven or ant. It's not difficult, for example in a maven project mvn package command should do the job.

Comment: @ZaidKhan For maven project take a look here: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, since you are using eclipse is to just export your project as war and then put that war (naming it PMS) in webapps directory in your tomcat.

Once started, Tomcat will deploy that war on `http://localhost:8080/PMS`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following steps:

1. Right click on project>> Export (Export as WAR file).
   or if you are using a maven project then you can give a maven build.
2. Copy that WAR file, (you will get that war file inside the project folder in your workspace) to the tomcat_Installed_Folder/ webapps
3. Inorder to deploy the app from outside eclipse, 
    goto tomcat_Installed_Folder/bin
   and double click on startup.bat

   then you could see a console.
4. For detailed logs of deployment, goto tomcat_Installed_Folder/logs

ALL THE BEST :)

Comment: ,i'm not doing maven project,i've simply created dynamic web project,spring framework...
what shoud i do to convert it into maven project....thanks.

Comment: You can export it as WAR even if you creating a Dynamic Web Project.
No need to convert to maven project.

Try this tutorial for creating a Maven project _http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/

Comment: Yes your above comment was really useful,thanks...(:

Comment: Select this as the answer, so that others could also use it :)

Comment: Sorry but you half answer that "You can export it as WAR even if you creating a Dynamic Web Project. No need to convert to maven project." And gipinani's tomcat manager suggestions both worked for me....and  I couldn't select both...:-)